# simplify the function, and implement them with two-level NAND gate circuits

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$(A'+C'+D')(A'+C')(C'+D')$$

how to simplify it. i got $A'D'C'$, but it's probably wrong. can someone help me

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  The idea is that you provide some thoughts or work in addition to just a question like this ... So, can you show us your work how you got to A'D'C'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll help you with the simplifying: $$\begin{align}(A'+C'+D')(A'+C')(C'+D') &= C'+ (A'+D')(A'D') \\ \\ 
&= \color{blue}{C'+ A'D'}\end{align}$$